# Getting php value in html

Tags: php, html, forms, htmlfill

I am trying to display the name retrieved from Database in html file . Referred couple of blogs, still I am not able to display the value

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from `Data`  where Emp_Id = $EmpID")
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
$Emp_ID=$info['Emp_ID'];
<html><head>
<body>
<input  name="emp_number" value=<?php echo $Emp_ID?>/>
<input name='emp_name' value="<?php echo (isset($Emp_ID) ? htmlspecialchars($Emp_ID) : ''); ?>" />
<input name='emp_name'<?php echo (isset($Emp_Name)) ? ('value = "'.$Emp_Name.'"') : "value = \"\""; ?>/>

</body></head></html>
?>
```

Tried three ways, but none of them worked.

Comment: and please close php tags after $Emp_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a template system.
Beside of that try this:

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from `Data`  where Emp_Id = $EmpID")
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
$Emp_ID=$info['Emp_ID'];
?>

<html>
<body>

<input  name="emp_number" value=<?php echo $Emp_ID; ?>/>
<input name='emp_name' value="<?php echo (isset($Emp_ID) ? htmlspecialchars($Emp_ID) : ''); ?>" />
<input name='emp_name'<?php echo (isset($Emp_ID)) ? ('value = "'.$Emp_ID.'"') : "value = \"\""; ?>/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I was querying from db with emp_id, it was expecting int but the POST request was string. Resolved by typecasting to int.

Answer (score 1):

This is the third time this week I've seen a similar question to this.

- Please search SO and look for related questions
- $EmpID is never being set
- Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and your site is likely to soon get hacked
- Your query has a discrepancy between Emp_ID and your returned result Emp_Id
- You've got two input fields with the same name, so only one will be returned on Post/Get
- $Emp_Name is never set anywhere (guessing it should come form info?)
- Also on the third input, you should have a space before you echo your "value=" field

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `Emp_ID` in line three should be `Emp_Id` or the `Emp_Id` in line one should be `Emp_ID`.